# Deep Copy of Complex Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, object, copy

I am facing an issue for which I do not see clear solution.

I have a nested dictionary which contains dictionary of some custom objects. I would need to make a deep copy of this dictionary in order to modify some of its values without changing the original dictionary. Hence, I was thinking about making a deep copy of the dictionary.

However, for some reasons, the keys of the dictionary are objects having an overriding `__set_attr__()` method which prevent any modification of the attributes. Therefore, it appears that it is not possible to apply directly the `copy.deepcopy()` method.

See below a short code example:

```py
class SpecialKey:
      __slots__ = ('asset', )

      def __init__(self, asset):
          super(SpecialKey, self).__setattr__('asset',asset)

      def __setattr__(self):
          raise AttributeError("SpecialKey should not be changed")


import copy 

my_dict = {SpecialKey("test"): [1, 2, 3]}
my_dict_copied = copy.deepcopy(my_dict)
```

Comment: How is having a `__set_attr__()` method preventing you from _reading_ the dictionary to make a copy?

Comment: The only purpose of the__set_attr__() of the object contained in the dictionary is to raise an AttributeError. Hence it seems that I can make a copy.copy() of the dictionary but not a deepcopy since I have this AttributeError which is raised when trying. (Thanks for your answer!)

Comment: My point was that the use of `__set_attr__()` when making a copy is not obvious. Please [edit] your question and provide a runnable [mre].